# Loading value from C++ .DLL in C# always returns true

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm trying to learn how to make C++ DLLs so I could easily have missed something super basic.

I'm currently creating a DLL with C++ and then loading it into a testing environment written with C#

The Testing environment is in C# because I find Windows Forms easiest for building prototype GUIs.

I have a define in my DLL (C++)

```
#define BUILD_FOR_TESTBED
```

and a function I've made to find whether it was defined

```
//header file
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) extern bool WasBuiltForTestbed();

//source file
bool WasBuiltForTestbed()
{
#ifdef BUILD_FOR_TESTBED

    return true;

#endif // BUILD_FOR_TESTBED
#ifndef BUILD_FOR_TESTBED

    return false;

#endif // BUILD_FOR_TESTBED//
}
```

I then load the function in the testing environment (C#)

```
[DllImport(LIBRARY_PATH, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool WasBuiltForTestbed();
```

And write it to the console in the testing environment

```
Console.WriteLine("Built For Testbed: " + WasBuiltForTestbed());
```

No matter what I do WasBuiltForTestbed() returns true once loaded into the testing environment.

**Q:** My question is, what am I missing here that makes the function always return true? How do I make the function return whether or not BUILD_FOR_TESTBED was defined?

Tests I've tried so far:

"Short Circuiting" the function and making it "return" true or false directly. It still only returns true.

```
bool WasBuiltForTestbed() { return false; }
```

Cleaning both the Library (C++) and Testing Environment (C#) builds. Then Rebuilding

Changing the name of the function WasBuiltForTestbed() to WasBuiltForrTestbed() in the library. The Testing Environment failed to load the function, so it's definitely finding something it thinks is the function and evaluating it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In c# you will get true whenever the number is no zero. So for some reason the the zero being set in c++ is not a zero in c#.  that often occurs when the size of the variable is different between c++ and c#.  So try : ((int)WasBuiltForTestbed()).ToString() to see what number is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET uses a 4 byte `bool`, but Visual C++ uses a 1 byte `bool`.  So you'll need a marshaling directive to tell the marshaler that what's coming in is just a single byte.  As it is, it's just marshaling 3 bytes of junk in addition to your `bool`.  The junk is usually non-zero, which is why your function appears to return `true`.

Add this to the DllImport.

`[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]`

As far as why .NET chose to make `bool` 4-bytes, it's likely that the main reason is to favor interop with C++ Windows APIs, which use the 4-byte `BOOL`, rather than Visual C++'s implementation of standard C++, which uses the 1-byte `bool`.

(Why the caveats?  Well, standard C++ does not actually specify the size of `bool`...)